# Environment variable is ignored on Docker compose

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, docker-compose, environment-variables

In my docker-compose I have a couple of variables which I want to pass to my Spring Boot Kotlin module. Part of my `docker-compose.yml` is

```yaml
version: '3.9'
services:
  tomcat:
    image: backend:latest
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
      - "5005:5005"
    container_name: tomcat
    environment:
      my-app_env_one: something
      spring_datasource_username: user
```

`my-app_env_one` is not available in my module but the `spring_datasource_username` still is. What am I doing wrong? I'm new to Docker, so sorry if I got something completely wrong. So the image is running right now but I have no idea why I don't get the variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Environment variables [cannot use](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/23659/can-shell-variable-name-include-a-hyphen-or-dash) `-` in its name.

Try this on any linux machine to replicate the error:

`export my-app_env_one=aaa`

You will get this error:

[image]

Change `-` to `_`:

```
my-app_env_one -> my_app_env_one
```

Also you can enable `debug=true` in your spring boot or inspect your container `docker inspect app_name` to get more details.

Comment: Thank you. That was the problem. 
I still don't know why it was working before. So i thought it must be something with the docker and my own docker image.

Thank you

Comment: #1 You are welcome. With research purposes, without docker, you could export your variable "my-var" with pure shell and verify is spring boot is able to read it. #2 Also to help future generations, you could change the title to something like this: Environment variable is ignored on docker compose. And remove the everything related to tomcat, because is not a tomcat error, spring boot, kotlin. Also add a tag: environment variables